# Mysql-how to assign value from a field of select into local variable?

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to assign a value from a field of a select statement to a local variable in my trigger. Does it have any way to do that?
Any help would be very appreciated
My trigger

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER update_cart_total
before insert 
ON core_cartdetails FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    declare total DOUBLE;
    select Total into total from core_cart where CartID = NEW.CartID;
    
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I don't see a problem with the published code other than it doesn't appear to accomplish anything. If you are getting an error please publish it in full. If it does not do as you wish add sample data and expected out come as text together with a statement of what you are trying to achieve. Also on an insert there may not yet be anything for the select to find.